# Как узнать список имён доступных сетей

Tags: c#, сеть, cmd

Как получить список названий всех доступных в данный момент сетей(проводных и нет)? Средствами стандартных консольных программ, похоже, этого не добиться. Может кто-нибудь привести код на C# или библиотеку подсказать какую?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 3):

Попробуйте использовать для wifi [ManagetWifiAPI](http://managedwifi.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest), а для изернета можно попробовать вот так

```
var address = NetworkInterface
.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
.Where(i => i.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211 ||
            i.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Ethernet)
.SelectMany(i => i.GetIPProperties().UnicastAddresses)
.Where(a => a.Address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
.Select(a => a.Address.ToString())
.ToList();
```

Если вы вызываете вот так

```
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Console.WriteLine(IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName);
    }
```

И у вас возвращает "пусто", то либо вы не в сети, либо название сети "пусто"(я не знаю возможно ли такое). У меня нет идей больше, почему это может происходить, возможно вам нужно создать отдельный вопрос на эту тему!

Comment: Не подскажите, как имя получить?

Comment: у NetworkInterface есть свойство Name

Comment: Имя сети оно не возвращает почему-то.

Comment: @Андрей возможно вы имеете ввиду это имя IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName

Comment: Почему - то пустая строка

Comment: @Андрей Проверьте подключены ли вы к сети.  Скиньте эту часть кода, где IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName возвращает пустую строку.

Comment: string Name = IPGlobalProperties
        MessageBox.Show(Name);

Comment: @Андрей ну вы же не так вызываете как я написал!

Comment: Извините,
string Name = IPGlobalProperties.GetIPGlobalProperties().DomainName;
MessageBox.Show(Name);

Comment: @Андрей поправил ответ!